# Azure devops widget "Assigned to me" doesn't change view based on queries

Tags: azure-devops

There was a query named "Assigned to me" that was automatically created when I added the widget.I changed the query from flatlist to work item and direct links, but when I refreshed to see the change in widget, it doesn't reflect the change, it still displays in a flatlist view. Could it be that the widget uses a default query and can't be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it be that the widget uses a default query and can't be changed?

The answer is yes.

The widget `Assigned to me` is not related to query `Assigned to me`, **it just happens to have the same name**. The query `Assigned to me` is created by default by Azure devops when we are creating a project. You can try to delete the query, the widget `Assigned to me` will still work normally：

[image]

[image]

**To achieve your request**, you could try to use the [Chart for work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#chart-for-work-items), which could select a **shared query** and [specify the chart type and values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=azure-devops#add-a-chart-widget-to-a-dashboard).

With this widget, we could custom the query.